# How to set height of <nav> in html or css

Tags: html, css, nav

How can I decrease the size of a `<nav>` tag in CSS? I cannot seem to figure it out. I have provided all of the code from my project below. My code did have PHP, but I have removed it due to it being unnecessary. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x5h226pp/), if you wish to preview the code there.

**HTML and CSS:**

```css
#top-menu {
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 100%;
  background: #1E1E1E;
  /*    display: table; */
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
nav ul {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
  border-width: 0;
  border: none;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
nav ul ul {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  height: auto;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
  background-color: orange;
}
nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
nav li#english a {
  background: url(images/english.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
nav li#english a:hover {
  background: url(images/english.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: orange;
}
nav li#english a.current {
  background: url(images/english.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  cursor: default;
}
/*--------------------------------------------*/

#menu {
  background-color: #1E1E1E;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
.clearfloat {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/*--------------------------------------------*/

#bottom {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1E1E1E;
  /*display: table; */
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-width: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
}
#bottom ul ul {
  display: none;
}
#bottom ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#bottom ul {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
}
#bottom ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
#bottom ul li {
  float: left;
}
#bottom ul li:hover:nth-child(1) {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#bottom ul li:hover:nth-child(2) {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#bottom ul li:hover {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
#bottom ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
#bottom ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#bottom ul ul {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
#bottom ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
#bottom ul ul li a {
  padding: 15px 40px;
  color: #fff;
}
#bottom ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
}
#bottom ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
/*--------------------------------------------*/

.bottommenuitem {
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 25px 40px;
  color: #757575;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html5>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Firma A/S</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssMenu.css">
</head>

<body>
  <nav id="top-menu">
    <p id="menu" style="margin-bottom: -25">
      <a href="Index.html">
        <img src="Tilbage.jpg" alt="Tilbage" width="243" height="243" />
      </a>
      <img src="Top_10.jpg" alt="" width="739" height="243" />
    </p>
    <nav id="top">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Velkommen</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">Firma A/S</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Koncern oversigt</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.php">Ejendomsselskaber</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Investeringsselskaber</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Øvrige selskaber</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Lukkede eller solgte selskaber</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Jubilæum</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Årsrapport</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Galleri</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="index.php">Kontaktoplysninger</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">Privat</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.php">Køb og salg</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="english" href="index.php">In English</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- PHP was here -->
    </nav>
  </nav>
  <div style="margin-top: 410; margin-bottom: 115">
    <!-- More PHP was here -->
  </div>
  <nav id="bottom">
    <ul>
      <li class="bottommenuitem">Firma A/S</li>
      <li class="bottommenuitem">phone No</li>
      <li><a href="mailto:xxxx@xxx.xx">xxx@xxx.xx</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What/Which html tag?

Comment: when do you want to decrease the height?

Comment: Yes, u can adjust the height

Comment: @Harshit: I have a "static" menuline locked to the top of the homepage which takes too much space in the height - and therefore I want to decrease the height of the NAV tag.

Comment: @Manish: Thank you very much - but how to do it?

Comment: @MichaelEriksen: Just give the nav the height u want, in ur css

Comment: The property `display:table` won't allow you to adjust the height or what so ever since the element will behave exactly as a table element.
You're going to have to remove that and adjust your items accordingly.
Also, I suggest using `position:relative` instead of float property.

Comment: @MichaelEriksen I posted an answer for you that shows how to do

Comment: @Manish: E.g. 35 or 35.

Comment: Rightly answered by @LGSon, see it

Comment: @LGSon I have tried to remove it - but I can't get it to work :-( Maybe I have misunderstood something or ... ?

Comment: @MichaelEriksen Doesn't my snippet below work here on SO?

Comment: @LGSon: Sorry I couldn't get it to work :-( I have removed "display: table;"

Comment: @MichaelEriksen Since my sample here on SO work I guess there is more code we haven't seen, that cause this to happen.

Comment: @LgSon: I have now posted all my code.

Comment: Please consider breaking your HTML code up a little bit; instead of using `<nav>`'s for all of the different sections, use `<header>` instead of `<nav id="top">` (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp) and `<footer>` for `<nav id="bottom">` (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp). This way, your code will be more readable and maintainable for other people to help you out/ use your code, etc. Just a suggestion, though.

Comment: @MichaelEriksen I deleted my answer since your code is such a mess and I have no time now to clean it up properly

Comment: @LgSon: Sorry for the mess - but I am a newbie. Hoping for your understanding. I really appreciate your time to help me. All irrelevant PHP-code has now been removed and my question has been updated

Comment: @MichaelEriksen I undeleted and updated my answer

Comment: @LGSon: Thanks for taking your time to help me - but I'm so sorry that I must tell you that I can't get it to work :-(

Comment: There are 2 nav tags. Which ones height do you want to modify?

Comment: @Harshit: The inner NAV.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
nav ul {
    background: #1e1e1e none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: white;
    display: inline-table;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1E1E1E;
  display: table;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  height: 25px;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
nav ul ul {
  display: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
nav ul {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-table;
  border-width: 0;
  border: none;
}
nav ul:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
}
nav ul li {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
nav ul li:hover a {
  color: #fff;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #757575;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  border-width: 0;
}
nav ul ul {
  background: #1E1E1E;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  border-width: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-top: 1px solid #6b727c;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #575f6a;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul ul li a {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: #fff;
  height: auto;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover {
  background: #4b545f;
  background-color: orange;
}
nav ul ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
nav li#english a {
  background: url(images/english.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
}
nav li#english a:hover {
  background: url(images/english.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-color: orange;
}
nav li#english a.current {
  background: url(images/english.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top-menu">
  <p id="menu" style="margin-bottom: -25">
    <a href="Index.html">
      <img src="Tilbage.jpg" alt="Tilbage" width="243" height="243" />
    </a>
    <img src="Top_10.jpg" alt="" width="739" height="243" />
  </p>
  <nav id="top">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.php">Velkommen</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Firma A/S</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="index.php">Koncern oversigt</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.php">Ejendomsselskaber</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="index.php">Investeringsselskaber</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="index.php">Øvrige selskaber</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="index.php">Lukkede eller solgte selskaber</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="index.php">Jubilæum</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="index.php">Årsrapport</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="index.php">Galleri</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="index.php">Kontaktoplysninger</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Privat</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.php">Køb og salg</a>
      </li>
      <li><a id="english" href="index.php">In English</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the fixed nav id=top-menu, just add a height to the CSS for the id selector. It works for me. If you have problems with it being overridden, make sure that it is placed lower in the CSS file or add `!important`
after the rule.

```
#top-menu {
    height: 6px;
}

#top-menu {
    height: 6px !important;
}
```